# Transform scale relative resizing

Tags: resize, zooming, transform, scale, effect

Is it possible to let the elements (next to the main element) adjust to the position it's scaling to?

My explanation may be terrible, but here is an image explanation.

[image]

So whenever i'm hovering on the main (middle) element. The padding on the left & right side will scale with it. See it as having an "relative" pop up of the image.

Comment: So you're saying that when you hover over the middle element, it will get slightly bigger to indicate the hover, and you want the left and right elements to move over slightly to compensate for the increased size of the middle element? Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: @samalamma708 That's correct. Whenever i'm hovering on the middle element I want that element to get bigger (scaling it up). But whenever I use the transform scale effect, it ignores the margin-right & left set.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the original left and right borders, say `leftOrig` and `rightOrig`. When you scale up, determine your new borders, `leftNew` and `rightNew`. Now all you have to do is shift the left element to the left by `abs(leftNew-leftOrig)`, and do similar thing for the right.

Comment: You may mind giving me an example since I have no clue on how to determine those values. I tried adding a new margin-right value whenever the item is getting hovered, but isn't giving me a smooth result at all.

Comment: That is hard to say without knowing anything about your code structure, or even the language you are using. You'll have to provide more details for that.

Comment: The transform property is a part of CSS3. I would like to solve this solution using CSS3 & JQuery.